# Generate non-identity primary key

Tags: linq-to-sql, primary-key

My workplace doesn't use identity columns or GUIDs for primary keys.  Instead, we retrieve "next IDs" from a table as needed, and increment the value for each insert.

Unfortunatly for me, LINQ-TO-SQL appears to be optimized around using identity columns.  So I need to query and update the "NextId" table whenever I perform an insert.  For simplicity, I do this during the creation of the new object:

```
var db = new DataContext( "...connection string..." );
var car = Car
{
    Id = GetNextId<Car>( db ),
    TopSpeed = 88.0
};
db.InsertOnSubmit( car );
db.SubmitChanges();
```

The GetNextId method is something like this:

```
public int GetNextId<T>( DataContext db )
{
    using ( var transaction = new TransactionScope ( TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew ) )
    {
        var nextId = (from n in db.GetTable<NextId> ()
                      where n.TableName == typeof(T).Name
                      select n).Single ();
        nextId.Value += 1;
        db.SubmitChanges ();
        transaction.Complete ();
        return nextId.Value - 1;
    }
}
```

Since all operations between creation of the data context and the call to SubmitChanges are part of one transaction, do I need to create a separate data context for retrieving next IDs?  Each time I need an ID, I need to query and update a table inside a transaction to prevent multiple apps from grabbing the same value.  The call to SubmitChanges() in the GetNextId() method would submit all previous operations, which I don't want to do.

Is a separate data context the only way, or is there something better I could try?

Comment: I would highly recommend your company changing the way they use a DB. This method is pretty bad. It doesn't promote proper relationsships, and doesn't insure data integrity.

Comment: I've brought up the issue a couple times.  Basically, GUIDs are too big (index fragmentation == bad performance).  We don't use SQL Server built-in replication, apparently due to reliability issues, so we can't use identity columns with the "not for replication" option.